# Does Group Finder work?

Tags: ps4, the-elder-scrolls-online

Just got really into ESO:TU, been able to get to level 20 mostly on my own, but one thing I'd love to do is be able to dungeon crawl on demand like in WoW. They do have a "Group Finder" option and you can choose which role you want and which dungeons to search for but  I queued up last night and didn't get matched into anything for over an hour, finally giving up on searching.

A couple key notes -

I only chose one role (damage) because that's what I am.
I chose "any dungeon" which had the option of about 6 different ones.
I resumed playing the game while "in queue" under "Group" menu item.
I'm on PS4.

So is Group Finder not working yet? did I do something wrong in the options? or did I just get unlucky with the wait time? or is this standard wait time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I haven't played the PS4 version since release, it should be working.

As with all such matchmaking things, wait times can be very long, if people don't join the queues or stick with them.

Overall the group finder has a few problems though:

- It used to be broken months ago (on PC/Mac; should be fixed now).
- People like to pretend it's still broken (such an easy topic to pick on).
- People want to find groups instantly - which is understandable - but someone has to do the first step. If everyone cancels after 30 seconds or so, there'll never be enough in the queue. This is unfortunately often the case I think.
- People are picky. They want to run dungeon X but only with people who've got ability y or have completed it and have achievement Z. While most aren't like that, it still reduces the pool of potential players.
- As a matter of fact, most people want to play a damage dealer. As such it's a lot more likely you're not invited to any group due to the lack of a healer or tank.

What you can try is picking one of the rarer played roles (tank or healer), which should definitely shorten queue times. If you know someone who'd like to join, form  your group first, then use the group finder to fill it. That way the group finder will pick people queueing up that fit your group (1 tank, 1 healer, 2 damage dealers). They don't have to queue up at the same time (you might find one player now, the other in 5 or 10 minutes).

Overall, I'd say its just important to mention that people should just do something else while waiting for the group finder. It would be nice to be an ad-hoc tool to get a group running within seconds, but unfortunately there aren't enough using it (yet?).

---

As an alternative, you could have a look at [ESO LFG](https://www.eso-lfg.com). It's a service setup by players where you can advertise wanting to form a group at some specific time frame and people can sign up to join you. Of course this isn't really ideal for something spontaneous.

Comment: Thanks for the details, and clearing up whether the Finder works or not. Looks like it SHOULD work but maybe doesn't, after sitting in the queue for over an hours (I periodically would check it) it never changed from 0/4, so it didn't look like it was finding ANYONE let alone people who were impatient. I did have luck just standing out side of a dungeon though, many players were there and some people invited me into their group which also makes me think there's something wrong with the Group Finder, or maybe not many low level players know about it yet...

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer, it works, but sometimes you have to wait. I never had to wait more that about 20 minutes, but I'm a healer in EU. Also I tend to requeue after some time (usually 10-15 minutes), thought I'm not sure what effect that has.

Answer (score 0):

I find the queue find doesn't work properly . I join it and end up joining a bunch of random people just questing near me . In ff online in queue find when u have a group it automatically puts u in your desired dungeon . Elder scrolls needs a serious patch to fix this dungeon problem because I feel I'm just playing a single player game . Hopefully they make it better because I'm losing faith and interest already